A wildcard in a Sql statement doesn't work
I'm building a program to manage a group of PC's worldwide. They are all stored in a MS Access database.
The program is written in Visual Studio basic
This is the query I run:
SELECT * 
FROM SidePC 
WHERE Hostname LIKE "NLYBSTQVP4W*"

When I run it directly in MS Access, it works like expected.
But in my application, the result set is empty.
When I use the query SELECT * FROM SidePC, I do get a lot of results.
Or when I pass in an existing Hostname without the *, it also works.
I use Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects to connect to the database.

The ANSI SQL wildcard LIKE character meaning any zero or more characters is %, not *.  So the ANSI version of your first query is:
SELECT *
FROM SidePC
WHERE Hostname LIKE 'NLYBSTQVP4W%';


Does this mean ActiveX Data Objects translates this to MS Access syntax?

@jarlh Nope, Access has 3 different SQL syntaxes, namely standard, ANSI compatible (also called SQL server compatible), and extended ANSI compatible. These have slight differences. ODBC and OLEDB connections, including those made by ADO, use the ANSI compatible syntax by default, and Access itself uses standard syntax but can be configured to use ANSI compatible syntax per database. Certain features are only supported in certain syntaxes (e.g. DDL with CHECK constraints is supported but requires ANSI compatible syntax)
